Double Slit Experiment for Electrons
Is there a minimum electron velocity in the double-slit experiment where interference emerges?

Low Energy Electron Diffraction of surfaces is routinely done at a few 10s of eV. Making and maintaining a well characterized beam is one reason it is not lower.

Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/836645/2451

Hi Sirius. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Hi Thanks for that. Unfortunately, I deleted it and then started a new question, but they would not allow that. So, I am not sure what to do

That question does not appear to be deleted.
